# How i can store data use this pattern - Object inside object inside object or object inside object inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Please give me answer use JavaScript code. How i can store data like this

```
let obj = new Object;
obj.prop = 5; // Good
// but when i put third value like obj.prop.newObjectInside= 5 /Return error/
// How i can do it? or for example 
obj.prop.array = 5 // Return error
```

I need add third object or array inside and use this pattern in my loop.

Thank you and if you know some articles or reference please write me too.

Comment: If you are using this pattern in your loop something tells me you need to rethink how you're writing the application in general

Comment: I think it would be better for you if you try to visualize with this way first:      let obj = {}; obj = {prop: 5}, obj = {prop : [ ], prop2: 5, prop3, "any string" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
obj.prop = { array : 5 }
```

or since it seems like you desire it to be an array you can do

```
obj.prop = { array : [5] }
```

You should then be able to do array ops like so

```
obj.prop.array.push(value);
```

Note the key here is to ensure that the second child is initialized, so you have to at least have an empty array

```
obj.prop = { array : [] }
```

Comment: Thank you and last question! ( "If you are using this pattern in your loop something tells me you need to rethink how you're writing the application in general" ) - Deryck . Are you think the same ?

Comment: I don't attempt to interpret what you intend to use this for, for all I know you may have a perfectly valid reason for going this route. I have done things like this before, so no I think it is fine.

Comment: @DanielMcColgan did this answer your question?